# Issue about XSS Attack and SQL Injection

Tags: php, security, mysqli, xss, sql-injection

I'm new to `web security`.After spending time reading some blogs and community sites like `SO`,I have found some techniques to be safe from `XSS Attack` and `SQL Injection`.But the problem is,most of that security related questions are very old.So,my question is

`does my following code has any major security holes that can be bypassed by amateur or mid-level attacker(hacker)`.

Is there anything else I can do to be safe from attack?By the way,I'm using `HTMLPurifier` to be safe from `XSS Attack`

**PHP**

```
require_once '/path/to/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

$connect_dude=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','user');

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

if(isset($_POST["sub"])){
  $name=$_POST["namex"];
  $email=$_POST["email"];
  $ques=$_POST["ques"];
  $clean_name = $purifier->purify($name);
  $clean_email = $purifier->purify($email);
  $clean_ques = $purifier->purify($ques);

  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connect_dude);
     if(mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, 'INSERT INTO question (name,email,question) VALUES(?,?,?)')) {

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $clean_name, $clean_email, $clean_ques);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      }
}
```

**HTML FORM**

```
<div id="form">
  <form id="sub_form" action="ask.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <p id="nam" class="indi">Name</p><input type="text" id="namex" name="namex" placeholder="Your Name" required></br>
     <p id="ema" class="indi">Email</p><input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required></br>
     <p id="que" class="indi">Question</p><textarea id="ques" name="ques" placeholder="Question" required></textarea></br>
     <input type="submit" id="sub" name="sub" value="Send">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL stuff is fine, parameterised queries are the best-practice approach to prevent SQL injection.

The approach to XSS is... a bit weird.

HTMLPurifier is of use where you want to allow the user to input limited HTML markup. That can be reasonable for formattable freetext fields (like I'm guessing `ques` is) if you can't be bothered to go as far as providing your own custom mini-markup language like Markdown.

But do you really want the user to be able to input markup for all fields, including their name and e-mail address? Should I be able to have the name “Edw*ard **B<s>oi</s>***ng Jr”? Are users going to have to enter `&amp;` every time they want to use an ampersand?

A better approach is usually to accept plain text as it is, and then HTML-escape it at the point you insert it into an HTML page (eg with `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($value); ?>`) so that the exact string entered by the user appears in the page. The fields where you deliberately allow markup (and so use HTMLPurifier instead of htmlspecialchars) are typically very much exceptional cases.

Note that if you are injecting into other contexts you need different escaping functions: for example if you are injecting into a JavaScript string in a `<script>` block then you need JS-string escaping and neither `htmlspecialchars` nor HTMLPurifier will help you with that.

Comment: Thanks.It does make well sense.do you think that it would be better to use `preg_replace` to allow certain `characters` to sent to `database` for extra security

Comment: Input filtering (with regex or otherwise) would add no extra security to the database layer. You're already doing parameterised queries which is the right thing to get arbitrary characters into the database. It is not dangerous to hold any particular character in a database.

Comment: Input filtering is a good thing in general to enforce business rules about what values are valid for a particular field (eg to check a phone number is actually made out of numbers), and there are some very common filtering rules it makes sense to apply to most input fields (eg no control characters, except for newlines on deliberately multi-line fields, no invalid UTF-8 sequences on text fields etc). But these are general good-practice measures that just happen sometimes to mitigate injection issues, rather than the proper security fix for those issues (which is appropriate escaping).

Comment: Thanks a lot.I'll follow that for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps testing if each of the post variables are set and not just the `sub` one. Also, checking them in javascript as well before sending to php to rid the post of any unwanted characters. You can regex and test for empty strings in javascript for example.

The most checks - the better.

You can also use names that are not so common (abrv_page_name_email instead of simply "email").

Lots of stuff.

Regex and mysqli_real_escape_string are also common practice.

Comment: Will not checking more and more affect the performance?If I use `preg_replace` before `parameterised query`,would it help?

Comment: Of course more checks will affect performance, but I believe the integrity of your system is more important and the performance hit will not be much to notice. depends on the variable. Depending on what characters you allow for input, such as password, you may choose to do a number of things. I'm not as familiar with html_purify so I may delete my answer and stick to comments. But Check out mysql_real_escape_string, preg_replace, and sanitizing user input with javascript on client side prior to sending to the server. Also, always check your database as needed.

Comment: Javascript is lightning fast and will not affect server performance as it is client side. Therefore look for ways to increase security and input sanitization by implementing check via javascript and even specifying HTML5 input types.